# Is checking a bool more efficient than calling an empty function?

Tags: c++, performance, function, optimization, polymorphism

If I have an object `Foo` with a function `Bar()` that may or may not contain any actual functionality, is it faster to first check a public bool member `HasBar` to determine whether there's a point calling `Bar()` or just call the function regardless and have it return immediately if it does nothing?

I.e. given:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    bool HasBar;
    void Bar()
    {
    }
};
```

Is it better do this:

```
Foo myFoo;
if (myFoo.HasBar)
{
    myFoo.Bar();
}
```

..or this:

```
Foo myFoo;
myFoo.Bar();
```

Normally, I'd think that the latter would be optimized away by the compiler, but we are talking about objects that are dynamically instantiated by factories residing in DLLs that are dynamically loaded at runtime.

*Since I can already sense the "premature optimization" torches and pitchforks approaching, let me provide some context (aside from the fact that I am curious to know, regardless of what I am working on):*

This is part of an engine upon which other applications will run, so the more light-footed it is, the better (any optimization is good). There will be a tree of polymorphic `Foo` objects (maybe thousands) that are iterated over many times per second. Each iteration consists of 3 passes through the tree, and during each pass, a different function is called on each object.

For example, during the first pass, `Bar1()` will be called on each object, during the next `Bar2()` and on the last, `Bar3()`. Some objects are doing work in these functions, some are not. The iterator doesn't know, so it must just blindly call the appropriate function depending on the pass. Which is the reason behind the question - should it first check whether the current object meaningfully implements the respective function (e.g. by checking a flag exposed by each object) or should it just call it regardless?

Comment: "Is checking a bool more efficient than calling an empty function?" - Yes. Is that the right question to ask? Probably not.

Comment: You could check the value within the function and also inline the function delegating large work to another ().

Comment: @GavinH Subtext: If so, to what extent. And I really can't see why asking questions like this - about performance (and implicitly, how programs are executed) - are "not right to ask". If someone wonders about something, I think asking is the best way to settle it. I cannot know what questions to ask and not ask BEFORE I know their answers or the mechanisms governing them.

Comment: @d7samurai The difference in your specific case can only really be gauged by experimenting and timing the different methods. In nearly the time it took you write the question, you could have gained a definitive answer for yourself! Sorry if it sounds harsh, but that's the best way!

Comment: Sometimes questions and answers are not just about the conclusions, but also about the considerations and processes leading up to them.

Answer (score 1):

If no optimization is happening, checking a single bool variable is much cheaper than entering the function, allocating stuff on stack and jumping back. Though such kind of optimization is really premature still.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a big difference one way or the other, because you are trading a conditional for a call with an immediate return. Since your dynamic library is linked either way, you are paying for linking regardless of your choice.

The only situation when the approach with a boolean guard would save you some CPU cycles is when the function takes parameters which must be evaluated before the call, and the evaluation takes significant time.

There is a disadvantage to the approach with the guard, though: it introduces a coupling between the method and the boolean flag, so whoever implements this must keep in mind this connection. It is not explicit in code, so it is possible to code up a class with a nice and long implementation of `Bar`, which wouldn't be called simply because you have forgotten to switch `Foo` to `true`.

Great thing is, this is not something that you need to decide upfront: code it up and profile a particularly hard case to decide which way to go.

Comment: I suppose another argument is that with the boolean guard, there's the penalty for the conditional also in all the cases where it evaluates to `true` and _does_ call the function. And I agree with your point about the coupling. Plus I totally prefer the aesthetics of the blind calls anyway.

Comment: @d7samurai That too, but it's usually undetectable in comparison to the "payload" of a medium-sized function.

Comment: PS. Could you elaborate on what you meant by "you are paying for linking regardless of your choice"? How does the linking affect this (aside from the fact that it prevents the compiler from optimizing the call)?

Comment: @d7samurai If you could use a boolean flag that comes from a source other than your dynamically linked library (for example, from a config file) to avoid loading the dynamic library altogether at run-time, it would be a big win for performance. However, in case when both the flag and the function come from the same library, you need to load it at runtime before you could check the flag or call the function.

Comment: The libraries must be loaded in any case. The DLLs contain plugins. The plugins are factories that produce the objects that make up the tree in question. The host iterates over them so that they can do whatever it is they do (the host doesn't know). The DLL loading is only done at application startup, not during iteration. The function calling could happen as often as 100,000+ times per second - which is why I was wondering about the cost of perhaps half of the calls being immediate returns.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it because I was curious about it. I'm not a C++ expert so I just tested something to confuse the compiler, to don't let him optimize my code to destroy the test results. I tested it on a Win8 machine with Visual Studio 2012:

Foo.h

```
#pragma once
class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo(void);
      ~Foo(void);

      bool HasBar;
      int Bar();
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
Foo::Foo(void)    {    }
Foo::~Foo(void)    {    }
int Foo::Bar()
{
   int a = 1, b = 1;
   return a + b;
}
```

Main:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
{

    unsigned int start = clock();




    // call it because the bool is true
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){

        bool trueBool;
        int sum = 0;
        int expected = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < 100 + i; j++){
            sum +=j;
            expected +=j;
        }
        trueBool = sum == expected;

        Foo f1;
        int returnedNumber;
        if(f1.HasBar){
                            // same code as in Bar()
            int a = 1, b = 1;
            returnedNumber = a + b;
        }
    }

    unsigned int end = clock();


    printf("call it because the bool is true: %d",   end - start);
}

{
    unsigned int start = clock();

    // dont call it
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){

        bool trueBool;
        int sum = 0;
        int expected = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < 100 + i; j++){
            sum +=j;
            expected +=j;
        }
        trueBool = sum != expected;

        Foo f1;
        int returnedNumber;
        if(f1.HasBar){
                            // same code as in Bar()
            int a = 1, b = 1;
            returnedNumber = a + b;
        }

    }

    unsigned int end = clock();


    printf("dont call it: %d",   end - start);

}

{
    unsigned int start = clock();

    // call it anyway
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){

        bool trueBool;
        int sum = 0;
        int expected = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < 100 + i; j++){
            sum +=j;
            expected +=j;
        }
        trueBool = sum == expected;

        Foo f1;
        int returnedNumber;
        returnedNumber = f1.Bar();

    }

    unsigned int end = clock();
    printf("call it anyway: %d",   end - start);
}

return 0;
}
```

Results:

call it because the bool is true: 32446
dont call it (because the bool is false): 32713
call it anyway: 35224

It seams that the call for the function is a little bit slower then the assertion if the bool is true or false.

The order is not important. The similar test results appear if i move the "call it anyway" -test to the top. The test for the call for the function is always slower than the assertion for the bool.

Answer (score 1):

If a significant portion of calls could have been avoided, checking the `bool` is faster. Checking a `bool` is faster than a function call by quite a bit, but of course the code is less elegant if written this way.

However, if you're in a situation where you need to call this function on all the `Foo` objects in a batch, here's a way to make everyone happy:

Try having a pre-allocated array that's inside the DLL and gets populated with with `Foo` objects where the flag is true (you might not even need to store the bool anymore). This could be populated all at once in one pass over the `Foo` objects. It may be most elegant to make your getter/setter of `HasBar` on the `Foo` object add and remove from this container. You have to decide how to handle this detail in a way that's right for your code.

**Now, assuming you have such an array, you can just loop over it call `Bar` on everything in the array.**

This has a number of advantages:

- Avoids unneeded function calls.
- Avoids unneeded bool checks.
- Scales only by the `Foo` objects that have `HasBar == true` when you need to change the value of `HasBar`.
- Makes branches more predictable.
- Better locality of reference if you put objects in the array rather than pointers.
- Elegant and Performant code.

Is this faster in your case? You'll have to try it out and see.

Comment: The actual system is far more complicated that a single array of "Foo"s with "Bar()"s.. There are X DLLs, all containing Y variations of "Foo"s - and they are dynamically instantiated (and added to the collection - which is a tree) at run-time, based on actions performed by the user. Also, there are several passes performed on the tree, some that call "Foo", some that don't (and similarly with other functions, depending on the pass). One solution is of course to keep a separate tree for each pass, containing only those "Foo"s that exhibit the relevant behavior for that pass.

Comment: But my question was more of a general nature, regarding the relative performance of the two approaches - as a starting point so that I could make precisely such architectural choices.

Comment: @d7samurai,I see what you mean. I mostly wanted to point out there are ways to avoid this problem entirely if is a bottleneck; so in effect contrasting these two approaches wouldn't play-in. Of course this approach introduces a lot more dimension to the problem where the costs/benefits would need to be analyzed.

Comment: @d7samurai,Checking a bool is faster, so here is another thought that would make it more elegant: Maybe put the outer shell of the worker function in a header file, the part that checks the bool. This code will compile into whatever module it’s #included into and also be inlined.  After the bool is checked this can call into a C++ file that is compiled into the DLL itself. This would both encapsulate the functionality in an elegant way, and speed things up with the preliminary bool check before the actual function call (at least the one that generate function call assembly).